# Can not enter password

Tags: su

Am new at ubuntu i tried to install a kdeplasmadesktop addons, and by typing su -c 'yum update kdeplasma-addons' from the terminal it ask for password but can not type any in.

Thanks.

Comment: does not sound like Ubuntu ;) Just tyep your password, you will not see anything in the terminal when you type.

Comment: whats your username? and what ubuntu are you using

Comment: ubuntu with yum?

Comment: Hi. I use ubuntu 13.10 kdeplasmadesktop, and it says that there is authinticate error.

Comment: Hi and my user name is michael@michael-SVE1512H1EW

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't show you the password for security reasons. So just type it in as normal and hit enter.